# How to prove rounded any real number multiplied by natural number consists of combinations of integer part of real number

Tags: natural-numbers

$n,i,j \in\mathbb{N}$

$r \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$

$k = \left \lfloor{r}\right \rfloor  $ (integer part of $r$)

$round ()$ = round function to make an integer

$round (n \times r) = ik + j(k+1)$

For example, 
Assume that
$n = 8$,
$r = 3.2$,
then $round(8 \times 3.2) = round(25.6) = 26 = 2\times3 + 5\times(3+1)$.

how to prove this? or any related problems are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use [floor and ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) notation.

- Prove that
  $$n \lfloor r \rfloor \le \lfloor nr \rfloor \le \text{round}(nr) \le \lceil nr \rceil \le n \lceil r \rceil \le  n (\lfloor r \rfloor + 1).$$
- Let $k := \lfloor r \rfloor$.
  The natural numbers from $nk$ to $n(k+1)$ can be written as
  $$nk, (n-1)k + (k+1), (n-2)k + 2(k+1), \ldots, k + (n-1)(k+1), n(k+1).$$
  Note that $\text{round}(nr)$ must be one of the above.

Comment: Thank you so much!